# Why not makemigrations in Elastic Beanstalk Config File Django?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Go to aws's setup guide for deploying a django app to elastic beanstalk [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) and go to the **"Add a database migration configuration file"** section.

You'll see that in the `db-migrate.config` file, they migrate the django app when it is deployed. I am wondering why they do not run `makemigrations` as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on django, but from what I can understand (e.g. [here](https://sixfeetup.com/blog/django-migrate-or-makemigrations)), `makemigrations` should be run when you change your existing models.

In the tutorial there are **no changes made** to existing models, thus its not executed.

If you want you can add `makemigrations` command to the `db-migrate.config` and check if it will have effect.

Possible new version of `db-migrate.config`:

```
container_commands:
  10_makemigrate:
    command: "python manage.py makemigrations"
    leader_only: true
  20_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
```

Comment: Thanks again Marcin! At this point, I feel like I should be paying you as a mentor XD. This makes complete sense. Would you happen to know how to edit the `db-migrate.config` command? If not, that's fine, I'm sure I can find it.

Comment: @NGI No problem. I edited the answer. I'm not sure if new config will work, I would have to verify it myself on my eb instance.

Comment: Ill give it a shot. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not done is because `migrate` and `makemigrations` are two very different (though related) operations. While Marcin is right that there are no changes in the tutorial to warrant running `makemigrations`, that is not why this isn't added to the config file.

`makemigrations` just *generates* the migration files from any new or altered models, while `migrate` actually *runs* these migrations on the database. You ideally should not be generating migration files after deploying your code. These files should be generated before deploying, and then they will be deployed to the remote instances (just like any other code updates), which will then allow you to run `migrate` with them, and update the remote database.